# flock does not block

Tags: php, flock

Please explain why the code below blocks first execution (`1607061065`) and does not block the second one (`1664361639`) (the output is attached):

```php
<?php
$fileName = "file.txt";

$fp = fopen($fileName, "a");
if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) {
    $runId = rand();
    fwrite(
        $fp,
        "processing task [runId]: $runId; [pid]: ". getmypid() ." started \n" .
        (new DateTime())->format(DateTime::ATOM) . " \n\n"
    );

    sleep(3);
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
    fwrite(
        $fp,
        "processing task [runId]: $runId; [pid]: ". getmypid() ." finished \n" .
        (new DateTime())->format(DateTime::ATOM) . " \n\n"
    );
    fclose($fp);
    exit;
}
fwrite(
    $fp,
    "script is busy [pid]: ". getmypid() ." \n" .
    (new DateTime())->format(DateTime::ATOM) . " \n\n"
);
```

I am running this via `ab` utility which is able to send request concurrently:

```
ab -c 3 -n 8 http://localhost/
```

(it is run by 3 instances in parallel 8 times)

And this is what I have in `file.txt` after execution is finished:

```
processing task [runId]: 1607061065; [pid]: 2507 started
2022-12-22T17:03:22+00:00

processing task [runId]: 1607061065; [pid]: 2507 finished
2022-12-22T17:03:25+00:00

processing task [runId]: 1664361639; [pid]: 2503 started
2022-12-22T17:03:25+00:00

script is busy [pid]: 2507
2022-12-22T17:03:25+00:00

script is busy [pid]: 2502
2022-12-22T17:03:25+00:00

script is busy [pid]: 2502
2022-12-22T17:03:25+00:00

script is busy [pid]: 2507
2022-12-22T17:03:25+00:00

script is busy [pid]: 2502
2022-12-22T17:03:25+00:00

script is busy [pid]: 2507
2022-12-22T17:03:25+00:00

processing task [runId]: 1664361639; [pid]: 2503 finished
2022-12-22T17:03:28+00:00
```

Why `1607061065` blocks the first execution and why there is a second process exist which acuires lock `1664361639` which does not block the execution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `LOCK_NB` means non-blocking. It should never block for the lock.

Comment: I don't understand the issue. `1607061065` starts and then finishes before `1664361639` starts.

Comment: @apokryfos when `1607061065 ` is executed why  no one can write during this period of time and when `1664361639 ` is executed every worker is able to write ?

Comment: Use a file as your lock file. Dont write to it, just use it as the lock, then wrote your output somewhere else, the log for example, Most likely issue here is you have over written some messages, Note you dont have any messages from the 3rd instance

Comment: @RiggsFolly just checked your proposal - I created a separate file for writing content, the result is same

Comment: As far as I know the lock does not prevent other threads from writing to a file, it only prevents other threads from acquiring the lock

Comment: @apokryfos yes I think you are right, but it does not answer why my example gives such output

Comment: I don't know. I would think so many threads trying to concurrently update the same file would lead to undefined behavior. Could be the OS is just queuing the writes in a strange way.